# jq - convert an array in a pair

Tags: arrays, json, select, jq

I have a json array like this:

```
["abc", 0, "cd", 1]
```

I'm struggling to convert this in a csv:

```
"abc", 0
"cd", 1
```

It seems I'm far to find a solution, but I've tried with this:

```
jq '[ "abc","def", "cd", "nc"] | 
      to_entries | 
      (.[] | select(.key % 2 == 0))as $a, ( .[] | select(.key % 2 != 0) as $b ) | 
     [$a, $b] '
```

but this returns to me

```
jq: 1 compile error
```

I'm unable to understand how to take two elements for iteration.
Any help with this would be really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate even indices using `range` and use them for slicing the array:

```
range(0;length;2) as $i | .[$i:$i+2] | @csv
```

Note that `-r` option is required for producing proper CSV.

`.[$i:$i+2]` generates a subarray of length 2, containing the elements  from index `$i` (inclusive) to index `$i+2` (exclusive).